# Let Other Extensions Handle Proxy Settings

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to set proxy for a specific set of urls. The `chrome.proxy` allows to pass a bypass list but not a whitelist (pattern to only let certain requests through the proxy).

The following code works in my case (using pac script):

```
var config = {
    mode: "pac_script",
    pacScript: {
        data: "function FindProxyForURL(url, host) { if (shExpMatch(url, '*get_with_proxy*')) return 'PROXY 127.0.0.1:8888'; return DIRECT }"
    }
};
chrome.proxy.settings.set({ value: config, scope: 'regular' },
    function() {});
```

But the problem is, a lot of my users use other extensions like Proxy Sharp or Omega Proxy to handle their proxy needs. If I use the above code, they see "another extension is handling proxy settings" when they try to change options in these other extensions.

Since I only need a few urls to go through proxy, is there a way I can let the other extensions handle proxy settings for non matching urls?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy#type-ProxyConfig) you can only have either:

- Individual fixed proxy servers
- A PacScript to handle which proxy is used

But you can't have both or multiple of either.

Your best bet would to be to try be the last extension that configures the proxy, get the proxy settings and try to convert them all to a single PacScript proxy.

TL;DR: If you don't want to change the users other proxy settings, it's not possible.